# How do I create easily a PDF from an SVG with jsPDF?

Tags: pdf, svg, jspdf

I'm trying to create a pdf but I have some SVG pictures. I found information about this problem, but I just have to use JavaScript, that's to say, no jQuery.

I found jsPDF here : https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

There is the plugin **jspdf.plugin.sillysvgrenderer.js** (in the same folder) and where we can find an exemple of PDF created in the folder *test*.

But when I try to generate the PDF on my own, it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I got this plugin working, but only with SVG file from the tests and the I saw in the doc that only PATHs are supported :(

There is already the issue on github
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/384

If paths are ok for here is my code (it's more or less the code from the tests):

```
function demoSvgDocument() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var test = $.get('013_sillysvgrenderer.svg', function(svgText){
        var svgAsText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgText.documentElement);
        doc.addSVG(svgAsText, 20, 20, doc.internal.pageSize.width - 20*2)

        // Save the PDF
        doc.save('TestSVG.pdf');
    });
}
```

Another point to consider, you have to run all examples on a server. Otherwise you won't see any results probably because of the security

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: doc.addSVG is not a function

Comment: @SardarFaisal addSVG is not present anymore currently its addSvgAsImage

Answer (score 3):

Try **canvg** for that to covert SVG to Canvas. Then convert the canvas to base64 string using `.toDataURL()`.

More detailed answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35788928/2090459

Check the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Purushoth/hvs91vpq/

Canvg Repo: https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg

Comment: Note that this means the SVG is converted to a bitmap before being integrated into the PDF, so you'll lose the benefits of a vector format (usually lighter, resolution independent).

Comment: Yes @jcaron. jsPDF doesn't support SVG export. If you want you can try PDFkit. Check this example  http://pdfkit.org/demo/browser.html

Answer (score 1):

There now is [svg2pdf.js](https://github.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js) which uses [a fork](https://github.com/yWorks/jsPDF) of jsPDF. 
It has been created to solve this exact task: Exporting an SVG to a PDF.

Also in the meantime, jsPDF also added a demo that shows how to possibly export SVG [using canvg and the jsPDF canvas implementation](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/canvg_context2d/bar_graph_with_text_and_lines.html).

The two solutions have different advantages and disadvantages, so you might want to try both and see if one of them suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the canvas plugin that comes with jsPDF to render the SVG on the PDF with canvg. I've had to set a few dummy properties on the jsPDF canvas implementation, and disable the interactive/animation features of canvg for this to work without errors:

```
var jsPdfDoc = new jsPDF({
    // ... options ...
});

// ... whatever ...

// hack to make the jspdf canvas work with canvg
jsPdfDoc.canvas.childNodes = {}; 
jsPdfDoc.context2d.canvas = jsPdfDoc.canvas;
jsPdfDoc.context2d.font = undefined;

// use the canvg render the SVG onto the 
// PDF via the jsPDF canvas plugin.
canvg(jsPdfDoc.canvas, svgSource, {
    ignoreMouse: true,
    ignoreAnimation: true,
    ignoreDimensions: true,
    ignoreClear: true
});
```

This seems to me a much better solution than the SVG plugin for jsPDF, as canvg has much better support of SVG features. Note that the `width` and `height` properties should be set on the `<svg/>` element of your SVG for canvg to render it correctly (or at least so it seemed to me).

Answer (score 1):

I modified this from: https://medium.com/@benjamin.black/using-blob-from-svg-text-as-image-source-2a8947af7a8e

```
var yourSVG = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
//or use document.getElementById('yourSvgId'); etc.

yourSVG.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
yourSVG.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var serialSVG = serializer.serializeToString(yourSVG);

var svg = serialSVG;

var blob = new Blob([svg], {type: 'image/svg+xml'}); 
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var image = document.createElement('img');

// image.addEventListener('load', () => URL.revokeObjectURL(url), {once: true});    
//changed above line using babel to code below;

image.addEventListener('load', function () {
    return URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, { once: true });

image.src = url;

//Then just use your pdf.addImage() function as usual;
```