# Render Svg to Pdf using jspdf

Tags: svg, jspdf

I am having trouble in rendering svg element to pdf using jspdf . Iam using plugin https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/ to do this.

Below is my code

```
// I recommend to keep the svg visible as a preview
var tmp = document.getElementById("chartContainer");
var svgDoc = tmp.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
svgElementToPdf(svgDoc, pdf, {
scale: 72 / 96, // this is the ratio of px to pt units
removeInvalid: false // this removes elements that could not be translated to pdf from the source        svg
});
pdf.output('datauri'); // use output() to get the jsPDF buffer
```

It is generarting blank pdf. Please help

Comment: svgToPdf only support g,line,rect,ellipse,circle,text elements and a few attributes. Just play it as a simple demo.

Comment: @Priyesh Tiwari : i am getting same problem svg to pdf conversion, how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 13):

You can do that using **canvg**.

Step1: Get "SVG" markup code from DOM

```
var svg = document.getElementById('svg-container').innerHTML;

  if (svg)
    svg = svg.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').trim();
```

Step 2:
Use **canvg** to create **canvas** from svg.

```
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvg(canvas, svg);
```

Step 3:
Create image from canvas using `.toDataURL()`

```
  var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  // Generate PDF
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 40, 40, 75, 75);
  doc.save('test.pdf');
```

Check the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Purushoth/hvs91vpq/193/

Canvg Repo: https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't work on Firefox (I tried with FF47 Windows)

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on "Get PDF" @Purushoth, here is the error `ReferenceError: canvg is not defined`. It seems that the link is not set correctly in your jsfiddle : https://gabelerner.github.io/canvg/canvg.js doesn't exist. Could you update it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The external resources has been removed/moved it seems. But the code will work with correct external references.

Check here for more details,https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg.

Comment: It is fixed now, http://jsfiddle.net/Purushoth/hvs91vpq/ @Basj. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! Another problem for which I would donate 500 points at least :) If you open https://josephernest.github.io/Writing/, and write `$$x^2+1$$` it's rendering into math using "MathJax". Then it seems impossible to turn this into PDF with usual JS PDF libraries. Do you have an idea? https://github.com/josephernest/Writing

Comment: If the answer is helpful, you can upvote :)

MathJax is a js engine for LaTex and MathML. MathML is an application of XML. We can export to PDF if it is in SVG or Canvas format. Here is a fiddle that shows to display Math formulas in SVG format. Then we can export the SVG to PDF. http://jsfiddle.net/p3wuu2pw/7/  

You can write a new question explaining your problems. So it will be helpful to discuss. @Basj

Comment: Yes, it seems so... I spent days on this, with no success... Do you see if you can manage to export to PDF with https://github.com/josephernest/Writing/ ? It's 100% open source, and having PDF export would be amazing, and a great contribution to open source community :)

Comment: Yes it is possible to export. Please write another question so that it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Here is the question @Purushoth : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785850/render-mathjax-into-pdf. I'll start a big bounty because this question would be really helpful for the whole open-source community!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138014/discussion-between-purushoth-and-basj).

Comment: Thanks for showing a solution on _how one could get the visible part accordingly in your pdf_, but technically it isn't SVG and comes with all the downsides of a rasterized image.

Comment: Technically it is not possible to embedded a SVG to jsPDF document. You have to rasterize it , https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1740

@ThomasJunk

Comment: @Purushoth I know, because I am having just this problem of putting d3 as SVG in a PDF. But There is https://github.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js/tree/master which uses https://github.com/yWorks/jsPDF (their own fork). And they are working on a fusion with upstream.

Comment: What if you have dozens of SVGs on a given page?

Comment: @KirkRoss For all SVG the `id` should be unique so you can get whichever you want.
```
var svg1 = document.getElementById('svg-container-1').innerHTML;
var svg2 = document.getElementById('svg-container-2').innerHTML;
```
Then follow the same procedure mentioned above. You can loop it too.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried both [svg2pdf.js](https://github.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js/) and [addSvgAsImage](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-svg.html#%7EaddSvgAsImage) using [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) internally.
Both **didn't work** well for me, the resulting images in the pdf where either incorrectly positioned or displayed.

I've ended up doing the following which works very well:

1. convert the SVG to PNG without any libraries, see [my answer to "Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) in the browser"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64800570/9219743).
2. just add the result to the pdf using the normal [addImage method](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html)

Comment: Didn't work for me in Safari, just hung, no error

Comment: Your answer is the most easy, light and practical. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the current jspdf version (2.3.1) has an [addSvgAsImage method](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-svg.html#%7EaddSvgAsImage), but it takes the svg as a string. I guess you could use an ajax call to retrieve the SVG content, but I just have the SVG in my code and pass it in that way.

Comment: Thanks, this is way more better approach. Rather then converting svg to images back or converting svg to canvas which is not at all efficient if one want to achieve the sharpness in pdf.