# Barcode doesn't shown on PDF in Angular 6 (jsPDF & jsBarcode)

Tags: angular, jspdf, jsbarcode

I want to print my HTML to PDF. Everything is almost OK, but barcode shown correctly only on my web application page, but on the PDF shown partly, I don't know why.

my HTML code

```
<div *ngIf="flight" #content>
<div>
<label>departureCity: </label> {{flight.departureCity}}
</div>
<div>
<label>destinationCity: </label> {{flight.destinationCity}}
</div>
<label>List of tickets: </label>
<div *ngFor="let ticket of flight.tickets">
<label>Name: </label> {{ ticket.name }}<br/>
<label>Surname: </label> {{ ticket.surname }}<br/>
</div>
<svg id="barcode1"></svg>
<hr/>
</div>
<button (click)="downloadPDF()"> Download </button>
```

my typescript code

```
@ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;
public downloadPDF() {
const doc = new jsPDF(this.getBarcode());

const specialElementHandlers = {
  '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
const content = this.content.nativeElement;
doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
  'width': 190,
  'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
 });
doc.save('Test.pdf');
}

getBarcode() {
JsBarcode('#barcode1', this.getOrderNumber(), {
  format: 'CODE128',
  displayValue: true,
    <!---->
});
}

getOrderNumber() {
const number = 'R' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000000);
return number;
}
```

On my web application page everything is OK:

[image]

But on the PDF barcode shown only partly

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer, now it works.

I've changed in my HTML code:

`<canvas id="barcode"></canvas>`

And add this to my typescript code:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('barcode') as HTMLCanvasElement;
const jpegUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
doc.addImage(jpegUrl, 'JPEG', 20, 150, 50, 50);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **canvg** for that to covert SVG to Canvas. Then convert the canvas to base64 string using  `.toDataURL().`

More detailed answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35788928/2090459

And Demo here [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Purushoth/hvs91vpq/)

> Note that this means the SVG is converted to a bitmap before being
>   integrated into the PDF, so you'll lose the benefits of a vector
>   format