# How to converted SVG Files into PDF in JSPDF using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, pdf-generation, jspdf

I struggled to converted SVG Files into PDF using JSPDF. Here i Worked in following code.

```
 var doc = new jsPDF();
    var test = $.get('amChart.svg', function(svgText){
    //  console.log(svgText);
        var svgAsText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgText.documentElement);
        console.log(svgAsText);
        doc.addSVG(svgAsText, 20, 20, doc.internal.pageSize.width - 20*2)
//console.log(doc);
        // Save the PDF
  doc.output('datauri');
    });
```

I get this script from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340610/how-to-create-easily-a-pdf-from-a-svg-with-jspdf).Its results only **blank PDF**.When i `console.log(doc)` before output it will shown results.But it will not results in **PDF**...

And I also i working in **SVGELEMENTOPDF** function from this [GITHUB URL](https://github.com/CBiX/svgToPdf.js/) and I worked in this code also.

```
// I recommend to keep the svg visible as a preview
var svg = $('#container > svg').get(0);
// you should set the format dynamically, write [width, height] instead of 'a4'
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
svgElementToPdf(svg, pdf, {
    scale: 72/96, // this is the ratio of px to pt units
    removeInvalid: true // this removes elements that could not be translated to pdf from the source svg
});
pdf.output('datauri'); // use output() to get the jsPDF buffer
```

But I can`t achieved it..And kindly advise me... How to solve this problem in **JSPDF**

Comment: If you have access to the command like you could use a tool like wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ There is a lot of documentation out there to get you going. Keep in mind in order for it to render correctly you will need font packages installed on your OS.

Comment: Since generating PDF mostly serverside job, may be its better scrap complete webpage and convert full page into PDF using phantomjs

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to:

1. Use [svgCrowbar](https://github.com/NYTimes/svg-crowbar) to serialize the SVG

   ```
   var uri = svgCrowbar(eGraph);
   ```
2. Write the serialized SVG to a PNG dataURI using canvas

   ```
   // Create image object which will enable the graph to be saved (via canvas)
   var image = new Image();
   image.onload = function () {
       // Create canvas 
       var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
       canvas.width = image.width;
       canvas.height = image.height;
       var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

       // Save DataURI for later use
       window.sitescriptdata.dataURI[id] = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
       window.sitescriptdata.numDataURIsLoaded++;        

       ...

   };
   image.src = uri;
   ```
3. Use jsPDF.addImage() to embed that PNG into the PDF

Using this method I was able to embed multiple dynamically generated SVGs into a single PDF.  I'm not 100% happy with the outcome as the images on the PDF look distorted, but it might be that I need to do more tweaking of the jsPDF settings to get everything to look crisp.

Comment: You`re right @Ddddan..but SVG tags will give proper quality for pdf when i create Image , I give results with low quality PDF.so only i need SVG values into PDF using jsPDF