# Coverting HTML into PDF using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am working on AngularJs application which at certain point I have to convert some contents in the web page to PDF format

I tried many things but finally thanks to this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049956/generate-pdf-from-html-using-pdfmake-in-angularjs) 
and using this snippet of code

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 500,
                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
        }
    });
```

I used [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/%22pdfmake%22) to generate the pdf but the result is not actually a full pdf it just a base64 image contain all the page and exported as pdf file.

I am not able to select any text or click any link it just an image which not the perfect result

Is there anyway to produce real PDF file from HTML via angularJs or Javascript in general

**UPDATE :**

I tried [JsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

with there official demo

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

// We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
 var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
    return true;
  }
};

// All units are in the set measurement for the document
// This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
doc.fromHTML($('#render_me').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

but I get this error

> jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!

and unfortunately they don't have documentation event on github all the wiki pages are blank pages !!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks for your reply, I already tried it, but I get an error and I can't find any documentation on the website or even on github .. all there wiki pages just empty pages !!!

Comment: There's a demo on the front page of the jsPDF site. Try the text colours example. I found that whether you can select the text from the resulting PDF (which seemed to be your concern) depends somewhat on the PDF viewing software. For instance, using the built-in viewer in Chrome I could select the text, but when using NitroPDF on my machine I could not.

Comment: @ADyson I tried HTML render example which is what I wan't exactly, I know it will generate selectable text but I can't fix my error

Comment: Have you tried contacting them for help? There's a link on the website. There are also some demos of usage knocking around the web which may or may not help you address the issue.

Comment: @ADyson yes I saw the link, but I think I can't depend on a library with this boor documentation

Comment: It's working for me: http://jsbin.com/tipoheq/edit?html,js

Comment: @MoshFeu The JSBin link does not seem to work.

Comment: @Prime_Coder The script's url was broken (apparently they removed it) I fixed the bin with another file reference.. Thanks!

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks for updating the link, I added an image tag with src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg" in that jsBin and tried to run, a blank pdf is created without any image, can you please modify it to use an image tag?

Comment: SVG is tricky. See a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23340610/863110)