# How can I generate pdf of svg image

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code print is working fine but I am unable to create pdf of svg image.If I generate pdf then it is getting generated with blank output(blank pdf).I tried capture,js.pdf,dompdf,tcpdf but not works for me.

```js
function PrintElem(elem)
        {
            Popup($(elem).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) 
        {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'parent', 'height=400,width=600');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
            /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            mywindow.document.write(data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

            mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
            mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

            mywindow.print();
            mywindow.close();

            return true;
        }

        function pdf()
  {
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   var specialElementHandlers = {
       '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
           return true;
       }
   };  
   doc.fromHTML($('.parent').html(), 15, 15, {
          'width': 170,
              'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
      });
      doc.save('sample-file.pdf');      
  } 
        
  
        function capture() {
            html2canvas($('.panzoom'),{
                onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
                            var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                            var a = document.createElement('a');
                            a.href = imgString;
                            a.download = "image.png";
                            document.body.appendChild(a);
                           a.click();
                           document.body.removeChild(a);              
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_div">
    <div>
    <div class="nav_div">
    
    <input type="button" value="Print Map"  onclick="PrintElem('.parent')" />
         <input type="button" value="Download Map"  onclick="pdf()" />
      </div>    
  </div> 
        <div class="parent"> 
          <div class="panzoom" >
           <svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="100%"
    height="400px"  xml:space="preserve">
           <g id="LWPOLYLINE_45_">
           <polygon id="1" style="fill:#78AB46;stroke:#231F20;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="300,250 350,200 400,250 500,250 500,300 300,300" />
           </g>
           <g id="LWPOLYLINE_44_">
           <polygon id="2" style="fill:#78AB46;stroke:#231F20;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="350,200 400,150 500,250 400,250"  />
           </g>
           <g id="LWPOLYLINE_43_">
           <polygon id="3" style="fill:#78AB46;stroke:#231F20;stroke-miterlimit:10;"  points="400,150 600,150 580,250 600,300 500,250"/>
           </g>
           </svg>
    </div> 
  </div>
   <div class="pop_up_div">
     <div id="header_lot">     
     </div>

    <div id="show_form"></div>     
   </div>               
     </div>
```

Comment: Would [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35789038/6693643) help ?

Comment: No.I have used that but it is also not working in my case

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drr6sjxn/) based on your code, seems to work fine or did I miss something ?