# How to enhance the quality jsPDF output?

Tags: pdf, jspdf

I'm using ***jsPDF*** (https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to generate PDF out of web instance.
The quality of the PDF output is lesser than the actual web instance.
I have tried setting the image quality to 1 in the ***canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);*** but it didn't help.
Is this a known issue?
I'm using the ***addImage()*** method to put the image on the pdf before saving it.
Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can inject JavaScript into your web instance before the images are drawn and the images are drawn onto a canvas, you could fix your problem by capturing the vector instructions used to make up the images.

1. Convert the canvas to SVG using [canvas2svg.js](https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg): [Method to convert HTML5 canvas to SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8571294/5223757)

   > You create a mock canvas 2D context and then generate an SVG scene graph as you call canvas drawing commands. [...] You can't actually "transform" a canvas element that's been drawn to, as it's just a bitmap, so keep that in mind.
2. Add the SVG to the PDF document using `jspdf.plugin.sillysvgrenderer.js`: [How to create easily a PDF from a SVG with jsPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23340610/5223757)
   Note: this has limitations, so might not work properly.

This will add the images as native PDF objects.

Comment: Thanks! I've left it as it is. Surely will try later.